# Azure API Management (APIM) - API x-functions-key not in hearder

Tags: azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-cli, apim

I have a Azure Function App I recently imported into the Azure APIM using "az apim api import" cli command.  This will be part of the release pipeline.  So far, the imported API is working during my tests.  During my test, I need to manually include the x-functions-key in my header in order to work.  To avoid doing that, I:

- Created an app key in my function app
- Created a named value (with x-functions-key as the key) in APIM
- Associated a backend to this named value

When I test it out (from APIM Test portal).  I am getting "401".  Looking at the trace log, the x-functions-key key is not included in the header.  What am I missing?

BTW.  Did a comparison of importing function app using CLI vs thru the portal, I notice the below differenc:

-- VIA CLI - The Backend Target is using HTTP(s) endpoint.

-- VIA PORTAL - The Backend Target screen now looks different.  Example.  It has Azure Resources as the option.  The value is pointing to the named value.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update:  Was able to resolve the issue by using API policy. Add SetHTTPheader to the backend base policy.  Can find instructions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetHTTPheader

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-properties?tabs=azure-portal#use-a-named-value

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The API will be configured differently depending on when you imported API, but using Backends functionality is a great way to control how backend call should be constructed.

Comment: This is an old question - but how were you actually able to complete this? The policy is super easy to add - but I'm currently trying to automate this for function deployments using the Azure CLI. The import task creates the named value correctly & sets the backing service URI - but using the named value directly requires that it's attached as base inbound policy to every API.

Answer (score 0):

I kept finding this post in my quest to solve this problem through CI/CD - in case anyone else is running into this same problem - here is how I was able to solve it, albeit in a bit of a HACK way.

To re-summarize the problem - whenever I add the functions directly through the Azure portal, I am able to access them directly through the APIM Gateway just using the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` header. However, when I import them during my pipeline runs using an OpenApi spec APIM is creating the named value that corresponds to the function key but it is not automatically adding the `x-functions-key` header/`code` param to the inbound requests. This means the imported functions are expecting BOTH the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` header & also the `x-functions-key` header or `code` parameter.

First - I am using the Azure CLI & OpenApi spec to publish my functions post-deployment.

```
    az apim api import `
        --path 'my-function' `
        -g 'rg-someresourcegroup' `
        --api-id 'MyFunction' `
        --description 'This is my function' `
        --service-name 'apim-instance' `
        --specification-format 'OpenApi' `
        --specification-url 'https://func-myfunction.azurewebsites.net/api/openapi/v3.json' `
        --display-name 'MyFunction' `
        --api-version 'v1' `
        --api-version-set-id 'MyFunction-v1' `
        --subscription-key-header-name "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" `
        --subscription-key-query-param-name "subscription-key" `
        --protocols "https"
```

The named value that gets created in APIM this way uses the Azure Function Resource Name + `key` - in the example above that would be `func-myfunctionkey`. I am passing this value into my CI/CD task & Powershell script using the parameter `$WebAppName`.

Here is the policy snippet I am using to auto-add the `x-functions-key` to the function (you can also modify this to use the `?code=` param if desired).

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />

        <set-header name="x-functions-key" exists-action="override">
            <value>@@function-key@@</value>
        </set-header>
        <!-- Other policy stuff here -->
    </inbound>
    <!-- Other policy stuff here -->
</policies>
```

Then in my pipeline - I'm doing a 'replace tokens'-style task using powershell & uploading this policy document to the APIM endpoint.

```
Write-Host `n"Creating default inbound policy for Api: $ApiName"
$apimContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServiceName $ServiceName

$path = './apim-default-api-policy.xml'

## Replace the @@function-key@@ with the correct value.
$xml = (Get-Content -Raw $path) -Replace "@@function-key@@", "{{$WebAppName-key}}"

Set-AzApiManagementPolicy -Context $apimContext `
                          -Format 'application/vnd.ms-azure-apim.policy.raw+xml' `
                          -ApiId $ApiName `
                          -Policy $xml

Write-Host `n"Set policy for $ApiName"
```

Note that I'm using the `az` CLI for the import & Azure Powershell for the policy update - at the time of writing (05/2023) - the `az` CLI does not appear to support policy manipulation like this - hopefully, this feature is added down the line.

**EDIT** - I initially approached this problem purely with the `az` CLI - I have since found that it should be possible to do this with [Azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/new-azapimanagementbackend?view=azps-11.1.0) and the [set-backend APIM policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/set-backend-service-policy).